# Point Python Launcher to Anaconda Installation

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, anaconda

I am using Python 3.4 on Windows 7.

I would like to run a .py and .pyc file from the command line using my Anaconda python3 installation.

I also have a default python installation which comes bundled with the "Python Launcher" per [PEP 397](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/).

When I double-click on my python file, it launches with the standard Python interpreter rather than Anaconda. Of note is that my environment variables seem to be fine. Typing "python" into the command line yields an Anaconda Python prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created an environment through conda, you should first activate that environment before running the script.

```
activate envname
python scriptname.py
```